# Outlook VSTO: Renaming existing Attachments does not show the new name

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, email-attachments

I'm trying to rename existing Attachments (change the DisplayName) in Outlook with VSTO.

After the rename occurs, the new name is not visible in the currently open Window.

However, when a different Folder or Email is selected and then the original Email is selected again, then the Attachments are correctly shown as being renamed.

This seems to me to be some sort of "refresh" issue.

```
public void RenameAttachment(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Outlook.Attachment attachment = null;
        Outlook.AttachmentSelection selection = null;

        try
        {
            selection = control.Context as Outlook.AttachmentSelection;
            if (selection != null)
            {
                attachment = selection[1];

                if (attachment != null)
                {
                    attachment.DisplayName = "NewName12345"; //Sample
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachment);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selection);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(control.Context);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(control);
        }
    }
```

Do I need to perform a manual refresh?

If so, how do I refresh the current displayed Window so the User sees the new name of Attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the mentioned solutions, but nothing completely solved the issue for me. I resolved it with a workaround.

1. Download the attachment to disk
2. Remove the attachment from the MailItem
3. Commit changes (MailItem.Save)
4. Add the downloaded attachment with the desired new name
5. Commit changes (MailItem.Save)

This provides the functionality I want and makes sure that users do not have to refresh the email (navigate to another Folder and then select the Email again).

Comment: Keep in mind that will only work with regular by-value attachments, not embedded messages, and the attachment order might carnage.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to save the parent message ( `((dynamic)selection.Parent).Save();` ), but I don't think that attachment panel is dynamically refreshed when the attachment properties change.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to call the Save method on the mail item object to submit your changes to the store.

Second, Outlook may not propagate changes made via the Outlook object model until the object is released in the view. For example, you may try to close the item, save your changes and release any objects in the code. Only after these steps you may try to open the item with attachments.

> Do I need to perform a manual refresh?

Yes, Outlook may not refresh the UI immediately.

Comment: "Yes, Outlook may not refresh the UI immediately." How can I trigger a refresh?
Or does the User need to navigate to another Mail/Window?

Comment: There is no specific method for that unfortunately. Save and close the item releasing all references. When you do everything correctly the result will be visible on the UI.